# Passing string value to text box from 1 web form to another through javascript in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

[image]

When I click on look up, popup windows opens.I want Email address at respective text box of web form on clicking template field= Select with pop up window closed, through Java script.
If more information needed ,comment below

Answer (score 0):

When you click the lookup button you could execute the following code, being the var lookupUrl the url of the lookup screen

```
var lookupWindow = window.open(lookupUrl);
var result = "";
lookupWindow.closeEvent = function(email){
  result=email;
  console.log("closeEvent->"+email);
  lookupWindow.close();
}
```

And in the lookup screen when clicking on select you can execute the function `window.closeEvent("mytestemail@test.es");`

And the variable "result" in the window form will receive the passed value to the closeEvent function.

Instead of assigning the value to a variable you can assign it to the value of an input or to any other element.

Comment: can you ping me on hs71290@gmail.com

Comment: are you having any issues?